# haproxy redirect troubles to nginx with docker

Tags: haproxy, subdomain

My network is setup so that there is a subdomain test.test-domain.de, redirecting to an ip NN.NN.NN.NN to the port 5555. However browsing the subdomain, always gets me an https status code 301. I don't understand why this is not working and running into an 301 http code, haproxy is very difficult to understand for me syntax-wise.

```
frontend app-https
    mode http
    bind abns@app-https accept-proxy ssl crt path_to_pem_file/chain.pem alpn h2,http/1.1

    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto https


    ## routing based on websocket protocol header
    acl hdr_connection_upgrade hdr(Connection)  -i upgrade
    acl hdr_upgrade_websocket  hdr(Upgrade)     -i websocket

    use_backend websocket-servers if hdr_connection_upgrade hdr_upgrade_websocket

    maxconn 100000

    default_backend app-webserver

frontend app-http
    mode http
    bind abns@app-http accept-proxy
    redirect scheme https code 301
```

Comment: What is the problem with the redirect?

Comment: it will always result in 301 HTTP :/